# Working screenshot plugin for Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have tried 2 screenshot plugins for Phonegap, but none of them was working.
(I use Phonegap 3.5)

Here is one: [link](https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot). 
And here is the other: [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/88a57e1c232f604f73be5bd82868d711ac235424/Android/Screenshot)

Both of them is made for older versions of Phonegap and contains deprecated elements that

cause errors.

Can you suggest a working screenshot plugin for Phonegap, or a working way to take screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was my mistake. The first plugin works, I just didn't know how.

Comment: i am unable to install the first one in phonegap, you mentioned here. It gives me the error "cannot fint module  ..\plateform\browser\cordova\api.js" So do you have any solution?

Comment: @AsifMehmood Sorry, but I don't work with PhoneGap any more, and I don't remember, how I managed to work it.